# Redirecionamento com curl

Tags: php, libcurl, redirecionamento

Estou tentando fazer um login em uma conta com curl mas ele não passa para pagina final.

Mapa do site:

1. pagina do formulário.
2. pagina que recebe o post (o curl fica parado aqui). 200 OK
3. pagina restrita(o curl não chega aqui). 302 Object moved

alguém sabe o por que do curl não acessar essa pagina ou passar por ela?

Meu código.

```
$f = fopen('cookies.txt', 'w');
$fp = fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);


 $url = "";

 $postfields = array();
 $postfields[''] = '';
 $postfields[''] = ''; 
 $postfields[''] = '';
 $postfields[''] = ''; 
 $postfields[''] = '';
 $postfields[''] = ''; 
 $postfields[''] = '';
 $postfields[''] = '';

 $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt';

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array()));
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, -1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, -1);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname );
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
 $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
 $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 $status_url = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
 $err = curl_error($ch);
 //ob_start();
 $ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.
 $redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
 curl_close ($ch);

  echo $ret;
```

Comment: Essa opção -> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, -1), é realmente necessária?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa botar o parâmetro do CURL, onde permite que ele siga os redirecionamentos:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Cáso você queria limitar os redirecionamentos você pode usar esse parâmetro:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
```

Comment: Eu já fiz isso @Dante, mas não faz o direcionamento.